# c# database retrieving informations

Tags: c#, sql, database

I would like to know something .

I try to retrieve 2 files .

One is register for a group 2 , and one for a group 10 .

So the field is Files.Group .

One user is register to the group 1 and the group 10.

This is the query I use to retrieve files .

```
SELECT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, Files.Path, Files.[Group] FROM Files WHERE Files.[Group] = " + param + "ORDER BY Files.Id DESC"
```

Param is a cookie who get the group, creating a chain like this 2|10 .

This doesn't work actually.. And i don't know how can I pass in the query the two groups. Should I separate them by a coma ? like Files.Group = 2,10 ?

Or is it something else ? To pass 2 parameters ?

Comment: how about (Files.Group=2 OR Files.Group=10) ? google some SQL tutorials..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

You should use `SqlParameter` to prevent Sql injections. Use the `IN` Statetment to pass in a comma seperated list of you group ids.

#### Sample

```
// value from cookie
string groups = "2,10,99";

// Build where clause and params
List<string> where = new List<string>();
List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>();
foreach(string group in groups.Split(','))
{
    int groupId = Int32.Parse(group);
    string paramName = string.Format("@Group{0}", groupId);
    where.Add(paramName);
    param.Add(new SqlParameter(paramName, groupId));
}

// create command
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("My ConnectionString");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, " +
                            "Files.Path, Files.[Group] " +
                            "FROM Files " +
                            "WHERE Files.[Group] in (" + string.Join(",", param) + ")" +
                            "ORDER BY Files.Id DESC", myConnection);
command.Parameters.AddRange(param.ToArray());
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - IN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)
- [C# SqlParameter Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: While the data reader is reading I get Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2|10' to data type int.
Why ? My parameter is 2,10 and not 2|10 so why do I get this error ?

Comment: Yes but , if the user as 10 groups ?

Answer (score 5):

### Baseline Structure

I don't have your entire structure so I have created the following simplified version of it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files]
(
  [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Name] NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  [Group] INT NOT NULL -- Probably have a non-unique index over this.
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files] ([Name], [Group]) VALUES (N'My File 1', 1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files] ([Name], [Group]) VALUES (N'My File 2', 2);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files] ([Name], [Group]) VALUES (N'My File 3', 3);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files] ([Name], [Group]) VALUES (N'My File 4', 2);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files] ([Name], [Group]) VALUES (N'My File 5', 3);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Files] ([Name], [Group]) VALUES (N'My File 6', 5);
```

### Temp Table

You can insert the split values into a temp table and use a `WHERE EXISTS` against it - probably yielding decent performance.

```
-- This would be passed in from C#.
DECLARE @GroupsParam NVARCHAR(64) = N'2|3';

-- This is your SQL command, possibly a SPROC.
DECLARE @GroupsXML XML = N'<split><s>' + REPLACE(@GroupsParam, N'|', N'</s><s>') + '</s></split>';

-- Create an in-memory temp table to hold the temp data.
DECLARE @Groups TABLE
(
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Insert the records into the temp table.
INSERT INTO @Groups ([ID])
    SELECT x.value('.', 'INT')
    FROM @GroupsXML.nodes('/split/s') as records(x);

-- Use a WHERE EXISTS; which should have extremely good performance.
SELECT [F].[Name], [F].[Group] FROM [dbo].[Files] AS [F]
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Groups AS [G] WHERE [G].[ID] = [F].[Group]);
```

### Table-Values Parameters *(SQL 2008+ Only)*

SQL 2008 has a [neat feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) where you can send tables as parameters to the database. Clearly this will only work if you are [using SqlCommands correctly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175652.aspx) (Executing Parameterized SQL Statements), unlike your example (appending user-created values to a SQL string is ***extremely*** bad practice - learn how to use parameters) - as you need to pass in a `DataTable` which you can't do with a simple string value.

In order to use this you first need to create the value type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntList] AS TABLE
    ([Value] INT);
GO
```

Next we will do things properly and used a stored procedure - as this is a static query and there are some performance implications of using a sproc (query plan caching).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFiles]
    @Groups [dbo].[IntList] READONLY
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    SELECT [F].[Name], [F].[Group] FROM [dbo].[Files] AS [F]
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Groups AS [G] WHERE [G].[Value] = [F].[Group]);
END
GO
```

Next we need to hit this from C#, which is pretty straight-forward as we can create a table to do the call.

```
public static void GetFilesByGroups(string groupsQuery)
{
    GetFilesByGroups(groupsQuery.Split('|').Select(x => int.Parse(x)));
}

public static void GetFilesByGroups(params int[] groups)
{
    GetFilesByGroups((IEnumerable<int>)groups);
}

public static void GetFilesByGroups(IEnumerable<int> groups)
{
    // Create the DataTable that will contain our groups values.
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
    foreach (var group in groups)
        table.Rows.Add(group);

    using (var connection = CreateConnection())
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetFiles]";

        // Add the table like any other parameter.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Groups", table);

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Remember:** *Table-Valued Parameters* are only supported on SQL 2008 and later.

**Edit:** I would like to point out that there is likely a cross-over point in terms of performance between [dknaack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259110/430560) and the temp table approach. His will likely be faster for a small set of search-groups; where the temp table approach would probably be faster for a large set of search-groups. There is a possibility that table-valued parameters would nearly always be faster. This is all just theory based on what I know about how the SQL query engine works: temp table might do a merge or hash join where the TVP would hopefully do a nested loop. I haven't done any profiling (and haven't received enough upvotes to motivate me to do so) so I can't say for certain.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably (depending on your database) looking at using this:

```
IN (2, 10)
```

rather than an `=` operator.

Note that constructing SQL using string concatenation like this can expose your code to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities, and using a properly parameterised SQL query is generally better practice. However, in your case, where you have an indeterminate number of parameters, it is harder to achieve in practice.

Comment: While the data reader is reading I get Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2|10' to data type int.
Why ? My parameter is 2,10 and not 2|10 so why do I get this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Param in cookie to create a chain like 2,10.

Then, instead of using `=` you need to use `in ()` like this:

```
SELECT Files.Id, Files.Name, Files.Date, Files.Path, Files.[Group] FROM Files WHERE Files.[Group] in (" + param + ") ORDER BY Files.Id DESC"
```

---

Another thing that you got wrong was missing a space in `param + "ORDER` part.

Comment: So if it 2|10 it will be consider as a int ?
That's why i should use  coma ?

Comment: While the data reader is reading I get Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2|10' to data type int.
Why ? My parameter is 2,10 and not 2|10 so why do I get this error ?

Comment: The param file in the c# code needs to be a `string`. And you don't need to convert anything.

Comment: Have you used the new code that I put? You still need to use the `IN clause`. And another thing, I'm assuming `Files.[Group]` is `INT`.